# Get html output from tinymce with laravel

Tags: laravel, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm trying to implement tinymce 5 to my cms. I'm using Laravel 8.

```
    <div class="mt-5">
      <label for="crud-form-2" class="form-label">Description</label>
      <textarea id="editor"  name="innerText"></textarea>
   </div>


tinymce.init({
            selector: '#editor',
            plugins: [
                "advlist", "anchor", "autolink", "charmap", "code", "fullscreen",
                "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media",
                "preview", "searchreplace", "table", "visualblocks",
            ],
            toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        });
```

Lets say that I build some html structure on tinymce editor.

```
<h3>Some description</h2>
```

But when I post all form data, I can not access html structure. I only get '**Some Description'**  How can I get html output from tinymce.

Ajax version;

```
<form action="{{route('corporate.update')}}" method="POST">
 <div class="mt-5">
      <label for="crud-form-2" class="form-label">Açıklama</label>
      <textarea id="editor"  name="innerText"></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
 </form>
```

Javascript

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let route = $(this).data('route');
            let innerText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});
            let formData = $(this).serializeArray();

            $.ajax({
                url: route,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('body').css('cursor', 'progress');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response) {

                    }
                },
            });

        })
```

Comment: Check the request payload to see what is being sent to server via dev tools > network tab.

Comment: I'm not using Ajax. If I check what sent to my controller via dd($request->all()), I see "innerText" =>  "Some Description"

Comment: @TugceAksoz can you show full code of blade file with ajax implementation

Comment: @JohnLobo Hey. I added Ajax version of my code. On network payload, I can see html tags.

Comment: If you sure that you are not getting raw content, please remove `{format : 'raw'}` from `let innerText = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});` in your question.

Comment: @TugceAksoz You open h3 and closed h2, maybe TinyMCE itself checks and cuts out the wrong tags? try to parse and verify

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem but with CKEditor and laravel

I used a workaround is that I wrapped the content of the editor in a string and put that string in a JSON along with other properties (timestamps... those were specific to my case)

somehow that worked

the reason I thought this was a similar problem is that when I inspected the payload it did in fact send the html tags along but only when I dd() in laravel that the tags get removed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this and tell whether you got the desired  output

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent()

the activeEditor is current editor,but i use tinyMCE.get('editor1').getContent() can not get the value of my editor, hope it can help you
```

Tinymce API: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent

Comment: Hey. I'm getting html output correctly at textarea value. But if I post those values to my laravel controller, I get show only text, not html output.

I didn't use strip_tags etc in my controller. Just plain request, $request->innerText.